# Beautifulsoup convert multi-row table into list of dictionaries

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML table that I need converted into a list of dictionaries. There are minimal attributes on the table but I need to be able to parse it correctly. Here's the text:

```
<div class="table-container"><table><thead><tr><th class="table-header" colspan="100%"><div class="title">Runtime end of support dates</div></th></tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Identifier</th>
        <th>Operating system</th>
        <th>Deprecation Phase 1</th>
        <th>Deprecation Phase 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>.NET Core 3.1</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">dotnetcore3.1</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux 2</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Jan 20, 2023</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Feb 20, 2023</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Node.js 12</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">nodejs12.x</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux 2</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Nov 14, 2022</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Dec 14, 2022</p>
        </td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>.NET Core 2.1</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">dotnetcore2.1</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Jan 5, 2022</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Apr 13, 2022</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Python 3.6</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">python3.6</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>July 18, 2022</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Aug 29, 2022</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Python 2.7</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">python2.7</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>July 15, 2021</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>May 30, 2022</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Ruby 2.5</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">ruby2.5</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>July 30, 2021</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>March 31, 2022</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Node.js 10.x</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">nodejs10.x</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux 2</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>July 30, 2021</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Feb 14, 2022</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Node.js 8.10</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">nodejs8.10</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p> </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>March 6, 2020</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Node.js 6.10</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">nodejs6.10</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p> </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>August 12, 2019</p>
        </td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Node.js 4.3 edge</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">nodejs4.3-edge</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p> </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>April 30, 2019</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>
          <p>Node.js 4.3</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">nodejs4.3</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p> </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>March 6, 2020</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Node.js 0.10</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">nodejs</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p> </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>October 31, 2016</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>.NET Core 2.0</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">dotnetcore2.0</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p> </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>May 30, 2019</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>.NET Core 1.0</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p><code class="code">dotnetcore1.0</code></p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Amazon Linux</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p> </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>July 30, 2019</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </table></div>
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

headers = []
tables = soup.find_all("div", class_="table-container")
for table in tables:
    correct_table = bool(table.findAll(text="Runtime end of support dates"))
    if correct_table:
        rows = table.findAll("tr")
        for row in rows:
            # Header row
            if row.findAll("th", class_=None):
                for header in row.findAll("th"):
                    headers.append(header.string)
        for row in rows:
            pprint.pprint(row.findAll("td"))
```

Comment: *" have an HTML table that I need converted into a list of dictionaries."* Hi. Can you please be more specific? What would the list of dictionaries look like?

Comment: *"This is what I've got so far:"*. Can you please explain how this code snippet relates to the question? What does the code achieve? Does it produce an error? Does it miss some values? What is the issue? I know that comments often complain about questions that don't include code, but if you include some code without explaining how it relates to the question or how it fails to solve the problem that you are tackling or where you are stuck in the code-writing, then the question is better off without it.

Comment: Also, the `</thead>` tag is pretty suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeatifulSoup

html_doc = """... your HTML from the question ..."""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

header = [th.get_text(strip=True) for th in soup.select("th")[1:]]

out = []
for row in soup.select("tr:has(td)"):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("td")]
    out.append(dict(zip(header, tds)))

print(out)
```

Prints

```
[
    {
        "Name": ".NET Core 3.1",
        "Identifier": "dotnetcore3.1",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux 2",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "Jan 20, 2023",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "Feb 20, 2023",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Node.js 12",
        "Identifier": "nodejs12.x",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux 2",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "Nov 14, 2022",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "Dec 14, 2022",
    },
    {
        "Name": ".NET Core 2.1",
        "Identifier": "dotnetcore2.1",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "Jan 5, 2022",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "Apr 13, 2022",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Python 3.6",
        "Identifier": "python3.6",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "July 18, 2022",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "Aug 29, 2022",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Python 2.7",
        "Identifier": "python2.7",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "July 15, 2021",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "May 30, 2022",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Ruby 2.5",
        "Identifier": "ruby2.5",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "July 30, 2021",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "March 31, 2022",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Node.js 10.x",
        "Identifier": "nodejs10.x",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux 2",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "July 30, 2021",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "Feb 14, 2022",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Node.js 8.10",
        "Identifier": "nodejs8.10",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "March 6, 2020",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Node.js 6.10",
        "Identifier": "nodejs6.10",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "August 12, 2019",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Node.js 4.3 edge",
        "Identifier": "nodejs4.3-edge",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "April 30, 2019",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Node.js 4.3",
        "Identifier": "nodejs4.3",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "March 6, 2020",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Node.js 0.10",
        "Identifier": "nodejs",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "October 31, 2016",
    },
    {
        "Name": ".NET Core 2.0",
        "Identifier": "dotnetcore2.0",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "May 30, 2019",
    },
    {
        "Name": ".NET Core 1.0",
        "Identifier": "dotnetcore1.0",
        "Operating system": "Amazon Linux",
        "Deprecation Phase 1": "",
        "Deprecation Phase 2": "July 30, 2019",
    },
]
```